# How to change values in QDoubleSpinBoxes using with QDoubleSpinBoxes?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

Below is my example and my attempt of code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(469, 348)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frame)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.total_spin = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.frame)
        self.total_spin.setObjectName("total_spin")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.total_spin, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.totalLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.totalLabel.setObjectName("totalLabel")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.totalLabel, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.SpinBox_two = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.frame)
        self.SpinBox_two.setObjectName("SpinBox_two")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.SpinBox_two, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.two_amount = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.frame)
        self.two_amount.setObjectName("two_amount")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.two_amount, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.five_amount = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.frame)
        self.five_amount.setObjectName("five_amount")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.five_amount, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.SpinBox_one = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.frame)
        self.SpinBox_one.setObjectName("SpinBox_one")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.SpinBox_one, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.three_amount = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.frame)
        self.three_amount.setObjectName("three_amount")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.three_amount, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.one_amount = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.frame)
        self.one_amount.setObjectName("one_amount")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.one_amount, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.SpinBox_three = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.frame)
        self.SpinBox_three.setObjectName("SpinBox_three")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.SpinBox_three, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.SpinBox_four = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.frame)
        self.SpinBox_four.setObjectName("SpinBox_four")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.SpinBox_four, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.four_amount = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.frame)
        self.four_amount.setObjectName("four_amount")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.four_amount, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.SpinBox_five = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.frame)
        self.SpinBox_five.setObjectName("SpinBox_five")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.SpinBox_five, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 469, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        ####
        self.one_amount.setReadOnly(True)
        self.two_amount.setReadOnly(True)
        self.three_amount.setReadOnly(True)
        self.four_amount.setReadOnly(True)
        self.five_amount.setReadOnly(True)
        
        self.total_spin.setMaximum(99999999.99)
        self.one_amount.setMaximum(99999999.99)
        self.two_amount.setMaximum(99999999.99)
        self.three_amount.setMaximum(99999999.99)
        self.four_amount.setMaximum(99999999.99)
        self.five_amount.setMaximum(99999999.99)
        
        self.SpinBox_one.setMaximum(100.00)
        self.boxes = [self.SpinBox_one, self.SpinBox_two, self.SpinBox_three, self.SpinBox_four, self.SpinBox_five]

        self.SpinBox_one.valueChanged.connect(self.limit)
        self.SpinBox_two.valueChanged.connect(self.limit)
        self.SpinBox_three.valueChanged.connect(self.limit)
        self.SpinBox_four.valueChanged.connect(self.limit)
        ####
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.totalLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "total"))
        ###
    def limit(self, value):
        i = self.boxes.index(self.sender())
        total = value + sum(box.value() for box in self.boxes[:i])
        for box in self.boxes[i + 1:]:
            box.blockSignals(True) # Avoid extra calls to limit()
            box.setMaximum(100 - total)
            box.blockSignals(False)
            total += box.value()

        if self.SpinBox_one.valueChanged:
            self.one_amount.setValue(self.total_spin.value() / 100 * self.SpinBox_one.value())
        if self.SpinBox_two.valueChanged:
            self.two_amount.setValue(self.total_spin.value() / 100 * self.SpinBox_two.value())
        if self.SpinBox_three.valueChanged:
            self.three_amount.setValue(self.total_spin.value() / 100 * self.SpinBox_three.value())
        if self.SpinBox_four.valueChanged:
            self.four_amount.setValue(self.total_spin.value() / 100 * self.SpinBox_four.value())
        if self.SpinBox_five.valueChanged:
            self.five_amount.setValue(self.total_spin.value() / 100 * self.SpinBox_five.value())
        ###
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It has total_spin box that value will be set manually, And 5 QDoubleSpinBoxes are named `self.SpinBox_one, self.SpinBox_two, self.SpinBox_three, self.SpinBox_four, self.SpinBox_five` will be set values manually with limit of 100 percent all together using below code:

```
    def limit(self, value):
        i = self.boxes.index(self.sender())
        total = value + sum(box.value() for box in self.boxes[:i])
        for box in self.boxes[i + 1:]:
            box.blockSignals(True) # Avoid extra calls to limit()
            box.setMaximum(100 - total)
            box.blockSignals(False)
            total += box.value()
```

and another 5 QDoubleSpinBoxes are named `self.one_amount, self.SpinBox_three, self.SpinBox_four, self.SpinBox_five` will be set the values automatically when `self.SpinBox_one, self.SpinBox_two, self.SpinBox_three, self.SpinBox_four, self.SpinBox_five` values changed. For example: if self.SpinBox_one value changed that will do `self.total_spin.value() / 100 * self.SpinBox_one.value()` and will be set the calculated value in to `self.one_amount`. And remaining are also happening link this.
But last one(`self.SpinBox_five`) is not working. If `self.SpinBox_five.valueChanged` value changed its not caliculating and not setting the value.  `self.five_amount.setValue(self.total_spin.value() / 100 * self.SpinBox_five.value())`.  How to solve above issue and second one is: it should be not overwrite percentage values: for exampe: if i am setting 5  `self.SpinBox_one, self.SpinBox_two, self.SpinBox_three, self.SpinBox_four, self.SpinBox_five` values(percentage) as `50, 20, 10, 10, 10` and if i change the first value from 50 to 60 its changing last box 10 to 0. In this case if 100 percent packed that should be not changable in every QDoubleSpinBoxes. and if the values(percentage) are  `50, 20, 10, 10` and last one is empty. In this case one of above `self.SpinBox_one, self.SpinBox_two, self.SpinBox_three, self.SpinBox_four`   can be added remaining 10 percentage. after that should be pack. How to do this both.

Comment: you haven't connected `self.SpinBox_five` to any slot.

Comment: @Heike Yes. I missed this. Thank you.

Comment: @user3030327 you should only ask one question per post. Also, as already pointed out, using names like this is really not a good idea (for which you didn't explain the *actual* reason, and I strongly believe is for a *wrong* reason). Besides that, the second question is really confused, please try to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want all the spin boxes to lock when the total value is at 100, *and* not allow a spin box to overwrite the values of those below it. In that case the `limit` function will be simpler to implement, but consequently when the total value reaches 100, one of the spin boxes will need to be decreased before any of them can be increased.

Additionally these statements — `if self.SpinBox_one.valueChanged:` — are not comparing if that spin box emitted the signal (use `QObject.sender()` to do that). The `valueChanged` property points to a pyqtBoundSignal of that object and will always evaluate to True simply because it exists. A better structure now is to place your spin boxes in a dict.

```
self.boxes = {self.SpinBox_one: self.one_amount,
              self.SpinBox_two: self.two_amount,
              self.SpinBox_three: self.three_amount,
              self.SpinBox_four: self.four_amount,
              self.SpinBox_five: self.five_amount}
```

For each box set its maximum to its current value + the remaining amount out of 100. And the value for the spin box corresponding to the sender can be assigned without any comparisons.

```
def limit(self, value):
    remainder = 100 - sum(box.value() for box in self.boxes)
    for box in self.boxes:
        box.setMaximum(box.value() + remainder)

    self.boxes[self.sender()].setValue(self.total_spin.value() / 100 * value)
```

And just a reminder to connect SpinBox_five, as mentioned in the comments.

```
self.SpinBox_five.valueChanged.connect(self.limit)
```